# Use LINQ to concatenate multiple rows into single row (CSV property)

Tags: linq, csv, group-concat, linq-group

I'm looking for the LINQ equivalent to the Sybase's LIST() or MySQL's group_concat()

It'll convert:

```
User  Hobby
--------------
Bob   Football 
Bob   Golf 
Bob   Tennis 
Sue   Sleeping 
Sue   Drinking
```

To:

```
User  Hobby
--------------
Bob   Football, Golf, Tennis 
Sue   Sleeping, Drinking
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's the GroupBy operator. Are you using LINQ to Objects?

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var users = new[]
        {
            new { User="Bob", Hobby="Football" },
            new { User="Bob", Hobby="Golf" },
            new { User="Bob", Hobby="Tennis" },
            new { User="Sue", Hobby="Sleeping" },
            new { User="Sue", Hobby="Drinking" },
        };

        var groupedUsers = users.GroupBy(user => user.User);

        foreach (var group in groupedUsers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: ", group.Key);
            foreach (var entry in group)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}", entry.Hobby);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That does the grouping - can you manage the rest yourself?

Comment: It's also possible to replace the inner loop with `String.Join(", ", group.ToArray())`, as long as the number of elements is not very large.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to learn LINQ myself instead of constantly bugging you ;-)

Comment: Am I the only one that noticed the man is into sports while the woman's hobbies are sleeping and drinking?  You're terrible Jon Skeet!

Answer (score 5):

See if this solution helps you:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>() 
{ 
    new User {Name = "Bob", Hobby = "Football" },
    new User {Name = "Bob", Hobby = "Golf"},
    new User {Name = "Bob", Hobby = "Tennis"},
    new User {Name = "Sue", Hobby = "Sleeping"},
    new User {Name = "Sue", Hobby = "Drinking"}
};

var groupedUsers = from u in users
         group u by u.Name into g
         select new
         {
             Name = g.First<User>().Name,
             Hobby = g.Select(u => u.Hobby)
         };


foreach (var user in groupedUsers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", user.Name);
    foreach (var hobby in user.Hobby)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hobby: {0}", hobby);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

re the `_concat` aspect of your question, using:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions 
{  
    public static String AsJoined( this IEnumerable<String> enumerable )
    {
        return AsJoined( enumerable, "," );
    }

    public static String AsJoined( this IEnumerable<String> enumerable, String separator )
    {
        return String.Join( separator, enumerable.ToArray() );
    }
}
```

The outputting foreach in bruno conde and Jon Skeet's answers can become:

```
Console.WriteLine( "User:\tHobbies");
foreach ( var group in groupedUsers )
    Console.WriteLine( "{0}:\t{1}", group.Key, group.Select( g => g.Hobby ).AsJoined( ", " ) );
```

... and you'll get the precise result output format you asked for (yes, I know the others have already solved your problem, but its hard to resist!)

Comment: this is like MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` function. useful.

Comment: @Moshe L I guess these days I might replace `group.Select( g => g.Hobby ).AsJoined( ", " )` with `String.Join(",", from g in group select g.Hobby)` (This requires the overload of `String.Join` which takes `IEnumerable<T>`, which was introduced in .NET 4.0)

Comment: or just use on 3.5 `group.Select( g => g.Hobby ).ToArray()`.

Answer (score 3):

Or else we can do the following-

```
var users = new[]
                {
                new { User="Bob", Hobby="Football" },
                new { User="Bob", Hobby="Golf" },
                new { User="Bob", Hobby="Tennis" },
                new { User="Sue", Hobby="Sleeping" },
                new { User="Sue", Hobby="Drinking" },
                };

                var userList = users.ToList();
                var ug = (from user in users
                          group user by user.User into groupedUserList
                          select new { user = groupedUserList.Key, hobby = groupedUserList.Select(g =>g.Hobby)});

                var ug2 = (from groupeduser in ug
                          select new{ groupeduser.user, hobby =string.Join(",", groupeduser.hobby)});
```

Answer (score 2):

To do it in one Linq Statement. There is no way I'd recommend the code, but it shows that it could be done.

```
            var groupedUsers = from user in users
                           group user by user.User into userGroup
                           select new
                           {
                               User = userGroup.Key,
                               userHobies =
                                   userGroup.Aggregate((a, b) => 
                                       new { User = a.User, Hobby = (a.Hobby + ", " + b.Hobby) }).Hobby
                           }
                            ;
        foreach (var x in groupedUsers)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", x.User, x.userHobies));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

all answers is not good enough;

because this is a db query,but all of us do that just in memory;

diff is that some operation in memory will occuce a error can't trans to store expression;

```
var list = db.Users.GroupBy(s=>s.User).
             select(g=>new{user=g.Key,hobbys=g.select(s=>s.Hobby)}); // you can just do that from db

var result=list.ToList(); // this is important,to query data to memory;

var result2 = result.select(g=>new{user=g.Key,hobbyes=string.join(",",g.hobbyes)}; //then,do what you love in memory
```