# How to use in my application a SELECT statement that must return more than one record to show multiple values for a certain field (m:m relation)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I don't know if you got what I mean, but I'll try to explain it with an example.

Users Table

```
UsedId    UserName
--------  ----------
1         Mike
2         Raul
```

HasPrivileges  Table

```
UsedId       PrivilegeId      
--------     --------------
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            2
2            3
```

Privileges Table

```
PrivilegeId      Privilege
-------------    ------------
1                Create
2                Edit
3                Delete
```

now this is two tables users and privileges that has a many-to-many relation between them, so when I select all the users associated with the privileges they have, I get the in this examples 3 records or rows in result for Mike each one contains a privilege he has.

Now I need in my application to display a list of all the users with their privileges but INDEED i don't want my users to see a user three times to show all of his privileges or anything else instead I want it to display

```
User Id : 1
Name : Mike
Privileges : Create, Edit, Delete
```

or something close to this! ANY IDEAS GUYS !??

Comment: Hint: Writing in all-caps is considered screaming. And screaming is considered rude. So, please don't. ;)

Comment: Do you want some trick SQL to do output this, or a general in-code mechanism to group this data yourself?

Comment: @Tomalak- With all due respect caps refers to excitement in general...of course screaming would be rude and it's totally not my intention =) Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Tom- I think it's how SQL outputs the results so I think some trick in my c# code will be better..if you have other opinion it will be more than welcome =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ASP.NET and C# in your tags. Considering that what you intend to do is a presentational issue, do it in the presentation layer (i.e. with C#) and not in the data layer (i.e. with SQL). That's a lot easier, too.

For example, like shown here: [Use LINQ to concatenate multiple rows into single row (CSV property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614542/use-linq-to-concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-row-csv-property)

Comment: Yh i'm using C# in writing my ASP.NET presentational layer, but I'm actually using the classic way (sql and ado.net) instead...is this possible in any way considering the tools I'm using ?

Comment: +1 btw because that's what I need exactly, but I hope I'll find a way to do it in C# + Sql

Comment: @lKashef Maybe you are thinking to complicated. Just query the data and concatenate it in a for loop.

Comment: tbh I'm not that experienced, I just started developing month and a half ago, So I always try to consult people with more experienced, sometimes I think of a solution but when I ask people or post a question here I find that there's a know practice for doing such a thing...so I was hoping if it was not too much to see a bit of code or a little more details about the mechanism you think I should use -complication is not my passion-

Answer (score 2):

Ikashef, as Tomalak said, suppressing the repeating name from each of the name/permissions rows is a "presentation-layer" issue, i.e. how you display data to your users.

What you want to do is look at ADO.NET DataTable to get these rows back:

```
       Joe    1
       Joe    7
       Joe    8
       Tom    3
       Tom    7
       Tom    8
```

The DataTable has a Rows property, which contains a collection of rows. You can iterate over (i.e. visit in turn) each DataRow in the Rows collection. So read up on ADO.NET DataTable object and on collections classes and on the "for each" syntax.

Comment: Nice one, but I was hoping for pure SQL and C# code without getting involved in datasets and datatables and this complicated stuff! +1

Comment: btw I did the same thing using a while loop and iterated through the DataReader object but I'm having some kinda problem that I don't seem to understand yet..Hope you could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420229/the-page-page-load-event-vs-the-repeater-itemcommand :) Thanks in advance

Comment: @IKashef -- the ADO.NET classes will actually make your work easier, not harder, when working with data. That's what they're designed for.

Answer (score 2):

Ok there are 3 points I can identify with this current problem (I've got a similar thing in my own project).

### Bitwise

You can virtually eliminate one of your tables by using a bitfield as opposed to a join table. For example, rather than storing the HasPrivilages along with a privileges table.... You can do this:

```
UsedId       PrivilegeId      
--------     --------------
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            2
2            3
```

Could equate to:

```
UsedId       PrivilegeId      
--------     --------------
1            7 (equivalent of Create, Edit and Delete)
2            6 (equivalent of Create and Delete)
```

This is because Create = 1, Edit = 2 and Delete = 4. Combined, they form a single integer number. This can be differentiated using Bitwise operations, like & and | to produce combinations of permissions.

You'd declare your set of permissions, with the `Flags` attribute like

```
[Flags()]
public enum Permissions {
    Create = 1,
    Edit = 2,
    Delete = 4
}
```

When you read the value back, the enum will calculate the actual permissions for you, and you can work it out in your application by doing an operation such as:

```
bool canEdit = ((myUser.Permissions & Permissions.Edit) == Permissions.Edit);
```

If you have the appropriate Permissions enum, doing a `.ToString()` on that given instance will actually give you the permissions data you require. It is however preferable to give the enum an custom attribute so you can give each value a better name, or even make it language independent from a resource.

### Formatting for presentation

You can of course stick with what you've got, and use the example Tim has given. Iterate over the rows and essentially precalculate the text.

### Do it in SQL

Sometimes it's just easier to get SQL to do the work. I've done this a lot. If you're just getting DataTables back as opposed to reading them manually or using LINQ, this is a quick fix.
If you're using SQL Server 2005 or above, you can use code similar to:

```
SELECT  u.UserId, 
        u.UserName AS [Name],
        (
             SELECT     DISTINCT Privilege + ', '
             FROM       Privileges p2
                        INNER JOIN HasPrivileges j ON j.PrivilegeId = p2.PrivilegeId
             WHERE      j.UserId = u.UserId
             FOR XML PATH ('')
        ) AS [Privileges]
FROM    Users u
        INNER JOIN HasPrivileges h ON h.UserId = u.UserId
GROUP BY u.UserId, UserName
```

This outputs:

```
UserId  Name   Privileges
------- -----  -----------
1       Mike   Create, Delete, Edit, 
2       Paul   Delete, Edit,
```

This still isn't perfect. You'd have to load this into a temp table and strip the final "," char off the end of each Privileges column, or do it within your C# code.

Anyway just thought I'd offer some alternatives, Tom.

Comment: Wow! you really thought "a lot" about this :D thanks for the alternatives +1...but it's fair to mark Tomalak's answer because it was simple and I used his advice and iterated through my records and managed it within my C# code...but even though I think your solutions is a bit complicated but I like the effort..THANK YOU! :)

Comment: While the bit-wise representation is elegant and compact, it has its downsides: **1)** It's not relational. **2)** It's impossible to index or join effectively on bit masks. This impacts performance. **3)** It is hard to track who switched which bit when. Access control and -history for the bit mask are hard to implement. **4)** It is possible that conflicting bits can be on at the same time. You have to be very careful that all bits are completely orthogonal. **5)** There can be only so many bits before the underlying numeric type is full. **6)** It's hard to read/maintain without a UI.