# The Page Page_Load Event Vs The Repeater ItemCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm running some code in Page_Load then I store the results from this code in some local variables.

Now I use this local variables to assign them to the controls inside my repeater item template

The Problem Is >> the page doesn't displays the item template but there's no data bound to it..I think the repeater can't load the data assigned to it in the Page_Load and it get's initialized -life cycle related issues-

Any idea what the problem is exactly ? and how to solve this ?

**EDIT**

Some example code :

```
public partial class MyPage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        int UserId = 0;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString);

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From Users, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader;

            conn.Open();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

//I'm not sure if I need those two lines:
            AllBrandsRptr.DataSource = reader;
            AllBrandsRptr.DataBind();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                    UserId = (int)reader["UserId"];
            }
                conn.Close();

            }
        }


    protected void AllBrandsRptr_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        Label LabelTest = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("MyTestLabel");
        LabelTest.Text = UserId.ToString();

    }
```

**EDIT 2**

> My Sql SELECT Statement

```
string command1 = "SELECT Brands.BrandId, Brands.BrandName, Brands.BrandLogo, Brands.BrandWebsite, Brands.IsBrandVisible, Cuisines.CuisineType, VenueTypes.VenueTypeName FROM         Brands FULL OUTER JOIN BrandCuisines ON BrandCuisines.BrandId = Brands.BrandId FULL OUTER JOIN Cuisines ON Cuisines.CuisineId = BrandCuisines.CuisineId FULL OUTER JOIN BrandVenueTypes ON BrandVenueTypes.BrandId = Brands.BrandId FULL OUTER JOIN VenueTypes ON VenueTypes.VenueTypeId = BrandVenueTypes.VenueTypeId";
```

> My Filtration Code

```
            conn.Open();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            AllBrandsRptr.DataSource = reader;
            AllBrandsRptr.DataBind();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                  if (((int)reader["BrandId"]) == BrandId) //this line to pass collecting some info, if I already iterated through the same Id 
                  {
                    BrandId = (int)reader["BrandId"];
                    BrandName = (string)reader["BrandName"];
                    BrandLogo = (string)reader["BrandLogo"];
                    BrandWebsite = (string)reader["BrandWebsite"];
                    IsVisible = (bool)reader["IsBrandVisible"];
                  }

                if (reader["CuisineType"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    Cuisines += (string)reader["CuisineType"];
                }

                if (reader["VenueTypeName"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    VenueTypes += ", " + (string)reader["VenueTypeName"];
                }

                conn.Close();
```

> My Initial Problem

[How to use in my application a SELECT statement that must return more than one record to show multiple values for a certain field (m:m relation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419344/how-to-use-in-my-application-a-select-statement-that-must-return-more-than-one-re)

Comment: Can you show some code of what you're actually trying to do. Hard to tell what you've got so far.

Comment: @Phill- I Added some code..It seems like I don't need all this but I really do some filtration on my data within the while loop for more info you can check my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419344/how-to-use-in-my-application-a-select-statement-that-must-return-more-than-one-re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't manually iterate over the DataReader at all.  It is a forward-only tool.  Only the Repeater *or* your while loop may iterate through the results.  I believe your immediate problem is that your while loop is exhausting the DataReader before the Repeater renders.

When you call `DataBind()`, you're instructing the Repeater to render its template for every item in the collection you assigned as its `DataSource`.  So, any filtration would need to happen before. Ideally, you should probably add that filtration logic as a `where` clause to your SQL statement.

Can you be more specific about the real problem you're trying to solve?  It's hard to give you accurate advice otherwise.

---

**Update:**

Keep in mind that `while(reader.Read())` does not work like an event handler or otherwise similar to how it might semantically *sound*.  In other words, you aren't telling the program to do something when the DataReader is read, you're telling it to start reading through the data immediately (unrelated to the Repeater).

Here's what I suggest you try:

```
string sql = "Your current SQL here";
string connectionString = "Your connection string here";

// The using block ensures that the connection will be closed and freed up,
//  even if an unhandled exception occurs inside the block.
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  da.Fill(dt);

  AllBrandsRptr.DataSource = dt;
  AllBrandsRptr.DataBind();

  var cuisineTypes = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     select row["CuisineType"];

  string cuisines = string.Join(", ", cuisineTypes.Distinct());

  var venueTypes = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   select row["VenueTypeName"];

  string venues = string.Join(", ", venueTypes.Distinct());
}
```

By using a DataTable instead of DataReader, you're able to iterate through the data as many times as necessary.  The DataReader is more performant, *if* a single, forward-only read through the data is all you need, but the DataTable is much more powerful and is helpful in these situations beyond the DataReader's capabilities.

---

It's worth mentioning that if you care about this project in the long-term and want to make it maintainable, you should consider eventually moving some of this data access code to a separate layer.  You should strive to never have SQL statements or direct data access code in your .aspx.cs files.

Then, your code in Page_Load could be strongly typed and easier to work with:

```
List<Brand> brands = Brand.GetAllBrands();

AllBrandsRptr.DataSource = brands;
AllBrandsRptr.DataBind();

var cuisineTypes = from brand in brands
                   select brand.CuisineType;

string cuisines = string.join(", ", cuisineTypes.Distinct());

var venueTypes = from brand in brands
                 select brand.VenueType;

string venues = string.join(", ", venueTypes.Distinct());
```

Comment: @Dave Ward- I know it's a little hard to understand, But I'll try to make it as clear as possible. this is my last question which was entitled to solve the main problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419344/how-to-use-in-my-application-a-select-statement-that-must-return-more-than-one-re

and check the new edit in the answer for the exact filtration logic and the SELECT statement I'm using

Comment: @Dave Ward- That's some really good information thank you, Marked As Answer but I hope you'd be able to help out If I had further questions as you already familiar with my problem, I'll add my comments about the updated answer in another comment

Comment: @Dave Ward- I've always stayed away from DataTables since all I heard about them was bad performance, and I used Repeater with DataReader because they are the fastest tools available but maybe it's time that I need more powerful tools but don't you think solving the root problem using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614542/use-linq-to-concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-row-csv-property would be better ?   and I appreciate your Layer advice, I'm really into the architecture thing but I'm trying to learn how to achieve what I need the normal way then I'll upgrade my skills.

Comment: @Dave Ward- Sorry dude for bugging you with all these comments! but I started replying then I tried to apply your code but I was confused on how to use this code! is the proper place for it my Page_Load event ? I didn't accurately got your code output! I mean should I bind after I'm done with my ADO code ? I thought we'll need to use some kind of loop to iterate through every row to check if it's the same id so we could extract only the cuisine and venue info! and will I use the same approach for the ItemTemplate or do I need to do some edits ?...Really sorry!..Thanks a lot =)

Comment: As long as you need to use the results of the query multiple times, it's tough to make a DataReader work by itself. You don't need to worry terribly much about the speed difference. For something simple like this, the performance difference shouldn't be noticeable. When you assign the data object (DataTable or DataReader, either one) to the Repeater's DataSource and then call DataBind, the Repeater handles the looping itself. If you put my code in your Page_Load, it should get the Repeater rendered.