# ToDictionary on anonymous types

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I am trying to mimic a function that was already created in the code base I am working on. The first function works, but when I try to modify it to use strings in the dictionary it does not work.  I get System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.Int32,System.String],System.String] as a value for the comments.  I know that the first one is using average which is an aggregate but I cannot figure out how to aggregate the comments as they are strings.

```
public static Dictionary<int, double> getRatingAverages(string EventID)
        {
        List<tbMultipurposeVertical> allMain = DynamicData.Vertical.getRecords(EventID, appcode, -2).ToList();

        Dictionary<int, double> ratings;

        using (FBCDBDataContext db = new FBCDBDataContext())
            {
            ratings = db.tbMultipurposeVerticals.Where(v => v.eventid == EventID & v.appcode == "ratinglabel" & v.label == "Rater")
                .Select(v => new
                {
                    AbstractID = v.parent,
                    Rating = int.Parse(db.tbMultipurposeVerticals.First(r => r.parent == v.id & r.label == "Rating").value)
                })
                .GroupBy(r => r.AbstractID).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Select(r => r.Rating).Average());
            }


        return ratings;
        }


    public static Dictionary<int, string> getRatingComments(string EventID)
    {
        List<tbMultipurposeVertical> allMain = DynamicData.Vertical.getRecords(EventID, appcode, -2).ToList();

        Dictionary<int, string> comments;

        using (FBCDBDataContext db = new FBCDBDataContext())
        {
            comments = db.tbMultipurposeVerticals.Where(v => v.eventid == EventID & v.appcode == "ratinglabel" & v.label == "Rater")
                .Select(v => new 
                {
                    AbstractID = v.parent,
                    Comment = db.tbMultipurposeVerticals.First(r => r.parent == v.id & r.label == "Comment").ToString()

                })
                .GroupBy(r => r.AbstractID).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Select(r => r.Comment).ToString());
        }


        return comments;
    }
```

Comment: Try replacing v => v.Select(r => r.Comment).ToString() with v => v.FirstorDefault().Comment.

Comment: I would like to concate the values instead of taking the first item.  That is where I was getting stuck.

Comment: Yeah, there is probably a complex LINQ statement you could make or you could just group the stuff and use a foreach to compose the result set. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614542/use-linq-to-concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-row-csv-property

Answer (score 0):

In the first method, you are taking the average of the ratings (an aggregate method).  For the second method, you are now treating it as a single comment. 
It's not giving you what you expect because of the `.GroupBy()`

As Steve Greene suggests, either you can get the first comment (`v.First().ToString()` or `v.FirstOrDefault().ToString()`), or you can consider concatenating the comments (`v.Concat()`) if that makes sense in your application.

Otherwise you may want to make your dictionary to be of the form `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`

Comment: I understand that the group by needs to by used with some aggregate such as average.  For my application, I would like to keep the form Dictionary<int, string> but I do not know how to concatenate the comments.  I was looking at something like v => v.Select(r => r.Comment).Aggregate() but was unsure of how to use it.

Comment: @ChrisAtwood I'm not sure how performant it would be, but you can take advantage of `string.Join(string separator, IEnumerable<string>)` (aka: `.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => string.Join(" ", v.Select(x => x.Value)))`)
https://dotnetfiddle.net/tQeNSa