# How to concatenate different fields into one field with linq? C# .NET LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

**I have two related tables. For example**

### Students

```
 ----------------------
| Id        | Name     |
 ----------------------
| 1         | Federic  |
 ----------------------
| 2        |  Sancho   |
 ----------------------
```

### Teachers

```
----------------------------------
| Id        | Name  | Student_id  |
----------------------------------
| 1         | Jose  | 1           |
----------------------------------
| 2        | Carlos | 1           |
----------------------------------
| 3        | Eduardo| 2           |
----------------------------------
```

**And the result should be**

### Students

```
----------------------------------
| Id        | Name  | Teachers    |
----------------------------------
| 1     | Federic | Jose,carlos   |
----------------------------------
| 2        | Sancho| Eduardo       |
----------------------------------
```

**I need to make it in Linq**

Iam working with other tables but their work in the same way

```
var Technology = (from  tTechnology in Context.Technology

                                                 join tUsers in Context.Users on tTechnology.EnableBy equals tUsers.UserId into collection
                                                 from subCase in collection.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                 join tUsers2 in Context.Users on tTechnology.LastChangeBy equals tUsers2.UserId into collection2
                                                 from subCase2 in collection2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                 join tUsers3 in Context.Users on tTechnology.DisableBy equals tUsers3.UserId into collection3
                                                 from subCase3 in collection3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                 join tResolution in Context.Resolution on tTechnology.TechnologyId equals tResolution.TechnologyId 
                                                  into collection4
                                                  from subCase4 in collection4.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                                   where tTechnology.DisableDate == null


                             //orderby 

            select new
            {
                tTechnologyTechnologyId = tTechnology.TechnologyId,
                tTechnologyName = tTechnology.Name,
                tTechnologyDescription = tTechnology.Description,
                tCityName = tTechnology.City.Name,
                tStateName = tTechnology.City.State.Name,
                tCountryName = tTechnology.City.State.Country.Name,
                tResolutions = subCase4.Measure,


                tEnableBy = (subCase.Name == null ? null : subCase.Name) + "" + (subCase.FirstLastName == null ? null : subCase.FirstLastName) + " " + (subCase.SecondLastName == null ? null : subCase.SecondLastName),
                                     tEnableDate = tTechnology.EnableDate,
                                     tLastChangeDate = tTechnology.LastChangeDate,
                                     tLastChangeBy = (subCase2.Name == null ? null : subCase2.Name) + " " + (subCase2.FirstLastName == null ? null : subCase2.FirstLastName) + " " + (subCase2.SecondLastName == null ? null : subCase2.SecondLastName),
                                     tDisableDate = tTechnology.DisableDate,
                                     tDisableBy = (subCase3.Name == null ? null : subCase3.Name) + " " + (subCase3.FirstLastName == null ? null : subCase3.FirstLastName) + " " + (subCase3.SecondLastName == null ? null : subCase3.SecondLastName),

            });
```

And i want to put all the resolutions that a Technology has as the teachers for the students in the example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use LINQ to concatenate multiple rows into single row (CSV property)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614542/use-linq-to-concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-row-csv-property)

Comment: You have to group teachers by student and then use `string.Join` or `Enumerable.Aggregate` method.

Comment: It is not working, help me plz